# Moving a div/button with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made  a slide out sidebar that comes out when you press a button/div but I want the button / div to slide out with it too here is what I have tried

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>


<div id="header1">
<p>BillIsChill<p>
<div id="menubutton">
<hr id="hr1">
<hr id="hr2">
<hr id="hr3">
</div>



</div>


<?php include('sidebar.html');?>


<script src="/Scripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">      </script> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="desktopstyle.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_darkcyan.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarBETA.css" />     <body>


<script>
$(document).on("click", "#menubutton", function(){
$('#sidebarright').toggle('slow');
})
</script>
```

and here is my relevant style that i am using

```
#menubutton.open{
right: 205;
}
#menubutton{
display-inline;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#006666;
float:right;
border-radius:10px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-right:5px;
right: 5px;

}
#menubutton:hover{
background:cadetblue;
}
#sidebarright.open{
right: 1;
}      
#sidebarright{
 background: darkcyan;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 2;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width: 200px;
 float: right;
 top: 0;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 transition: right 0.5s;
 right:-200;  
 }
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: Can you please add the HTML?

Comment: Although you could join the two event handlers together, there's nothing immediately wrong with the code you've shown. The issue must lay elsewhere in your CSS or JS code. Unfortunately no one can help you unless you edit your question to show that code.

Comment: It's just a div styled to look like a menu button and stuff for the header and linking style and php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think code blocks are not properly formatted. But below css should fix your issue.

```
#menubutton.open{
   right: 205;
}
#menubutton{
   display-inline;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   background:#006666;
   float:right;
   border-radius:10px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   margin-right:5px;
   right: 5px;
}
#menubutton:hover{
   background:cadetblue;
}
#sidebarright.open{
   right: 1;
}      
#sidebarright{
   background: darkcyan;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 2;
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   width: 200px;
   float: right;
   top: 60px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   transition: right 0.5s;
   right:-200;  
   overflow: auto;
 }
 #header1 {
  z-index: 3;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<body>
<style>
.open { display:none; }
#buttonWrapper, #optionsWrapper { float:left; }
ul { margin:0; }
</style>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="optionsWrapper">
    <div id="options" class="open">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="buttonWrapper">
  <button id="button">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#options').toggleClass('open');
})
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: i cant seem to get a smooth transition to work in css

Comment: it does the same thing im not shure what to do sir

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesn't want to save my changes. Therefore I created a new one: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/3xy28adn/

Comment: Ok i am very sorry but the button is still not sliding out with the sidebar, the sidebar slides out (wich is very nice by the way) but the button sort of fades off to the right here is my site [link](http://billischill.ddns.net) and the code has been updated above